# PHP AJAX Session Variable Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am new to using Session variables and have been struggling despite scouring the net to understand.

So basically I have a page (search.php). I load a dynamic data table based on a search form. Once the table is loaded, via AJAX I perform the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/ITSMIS/data/asset/search.php',
    data:HardwareAsset,
    dataType: 'html',
    // When PHP / SQL Query Has Been Executed If Data Is Returned
    success:function(data){
        // Load The Data Table Results
        LoadDataTable(data);
        // Generate Hyperlinks For The Table Rows

        $('#data-table tr').click(function(){       
            var HyperlinkHardwareAssetID = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/ITSMIS/session.php',
                data: HyperlinkHardwareAssetID,
                success: function(data){
                    alert("great!");
                }
            });
            window.location = $(this).data('href');
        }); 

    }
})
```

As you can see on Success and on click of a table row record, the idea is I post a variable via AJAX to use later. And redirect the user to the update.php page.

I am expecting to then create a session variable in the session.php page using the POSTED AJAX variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"] = $_POST["HyperlinkHardwareAssetID"];
```

I am then expected when the update.php page loads to display the Session variable result on the page.

```
        $session = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $session .= "/ITSMIS/session.php";
        include_once($session);

        echo $_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"];
```

But I only get the following error:

Notice: Undefined index: HyperlinkHardwareAssetID in C:\xampp\htdocs\ITSMIS\session.php on line 3

Implying for some reason the AJAX POST on click of the table row hasnt worked. However the alert with the success is always triggered.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ajax data param as an object {key:value}

```
   $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/ITSMIS/session.php',
            data: {HyperlinkHardwareAssetID : HyperlinkHardwareAssetID  },
            success: function(data){
                alert("great!");
            }
    });
```

Comment: I thanks for the advice, i noticed i was originally missing this, I have since tried this but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

To send variables to your php, you have to send an object in `data` property of `$.ajax` function, like:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        'var_name': 'value'
    }
});
```

and, in the PHP file:

```
$item = $_POST['var_name'];
```

So, in your code, you should use your $.ajax function this way:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'/ITSMIS/session.php',
   data: {
       'HyperlinkHardwareAssetID': HyperlinkHardwareAssetID
   },
   success: function(data){
       alert("great!");
   }
});
```

For more information, see [jQuery.ajax() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: thanks, after you shared this info, it made sense why I needed to do this, I have done it everywhere else in my code, however this hasnt resolved my error message, any ideas?

Comment: Insert a `print_r($_POST)` in your PHP file, and in the `$.ajax`, insert a new data variable, like: `data: {'HyperlinkHardwareAssetID': HyperlinkHardwareAssetID, 'hello': 'Hi there!'}`.  
It seems like your `HyperlinkHardwareAssetID` has an undefined value, and those values doesn't appear in the `$_POST` variable.  
If you want to get the `tr` attribute with jQuery, use `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `$(this).data('id')`, and do the same with `$(this).data('href')`

Comment: On closer look at the code, when i try and check what "data" is in success, it says undefined....